# Para que serve o argumento inteiro em exit()?

Tags: php

No PHP, quando queremos encerrar um script, geralmente utilizamos a função `exit()`.

Quando utilizamos strings, ele encerra a execução do *script* e imprime essa *string*.

Exemplo:

```
exit('Stack Overflow'); // Stack Overflow
```

Porém, se utilizamos um valor do tipo `int`, ele não o retorna;

Exemplo:

```
exit(0); // Nada é retornado
```

Imagino que isso deve servir para alguma funcionalidade interna dessa função.

Mas afinal, pra que serve essa parâmetro inteiro no `exit()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) diz:

> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed.

Ou seja, se passado um inteiro ele será usado só como código de estado e não imprimido na página. Aparentemente é assim desde PHP `>= 4.2.0`.

Answer (score 8):

Ele retorna este valor para o que chamou o *script* PHP, no caso o *shell* do sistema operacional. Até onde eu sei isto não serve para nada se estiver usando um servidor HTTP.

Obviamente só o *shell* saberá o que fazer com este código de erro que ele receberá do PHP. Portanto há uma diferença semântica nesta construção quando utiliza uma *string* ou um número.

Zero indica ausência de erros, outro número indica o motivo da falha do *script*.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Comment: Só pra eu entender. Esse `0` a `255` é por causa dos valores das constantes `E_ALL` , `E_ERROR` e etc?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não. Este número é você que coloca para indicar o que você quiser.

Answer (score 3):

Se um valor inteiro é passado, nada é retornado. O parâmetro 0, indica que o código executado teve sucesso. O parâmetro 1 é o oposto, ou seja, indica que ouve algum erro no código.