# Por que definir uma saída 0 ou 1 no final de um programa?

Tags: sistema-operacional

Já percebi que alguns programas sempre há um trecho de código, que sempre é executado por último, que recebe como parâmetro um número, geralmente `0` ou `1`.

Para melhor compreensão, coloquei esse exemplo de uma aplicação PyQt:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QtGui.QWidget()

win.show()

ret = app.exec_()

#quando eu fecho a aplicação, retorna 0
print ret

# todos os tutoriais que li, ensinam a colocar essa linha 
# com esse retorno
sys.exit(ret)
```

**Minhas curiosidades**

Em C, já percebi que o método `int main` costuma-se retornar um `int`. Geralmente, retornam `0` (não sei se está relacionado também).

Em alguns scripts PHP, já vi sendo retornado `0` ou `1` também no final da execução de um programa.

Como por exemplo

```
exit(0);
```

Enfim, eu gostaria de saber o que significa esses números que geralmente são definidos na "última linha" do código de um programa.

**Perguntas**

- Quais são os significados de finalizar um programa com `0` ou `1`?
- Somente `0` e `1` devem ser usados? Ou existem outros números, com significados específicos?
- Qual é o nome dado para esse tipo de saída da aplicação? Li em alguma resposta relacionada aqui no site que o termo *código de estado*, mas não tenho certeza se é isso.

Comment: Acho que é dup.

Comment: Também acho que é, mas eu não tenho ideia de como pesquisar isso.

Comment: Vixe, mas essa aí não explica por que tem que retornar 0 ou 1 e qual é o significado deles.

Comment: **Nota:** Eu previamente apontei duas possiveis duplicatas, mas ao analisar as perguntas e respostas vi que de fato o foco das explicações não era o mesmo que este e por isso eu (opinião pessoal) removi o meu voto de fechamento em favor de deixar aberta a pergunta por considerar que ainda não existe um resposta apropriada e é uma otima oportunidade de alguém responder, de qualquer maneira se tiverem um link para indicar fico grato.

Comment: Relacionado: [PHP - Pra que serve o argumento inteiro na função Exit](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77643/para-que-serve-o-argumento-inteiro-em-exit)

Answer (score 8):

Estes são os chamados **Return Codes**, que ficaram populares em Windows como `ERRORLEVEL` que é o nome da variável de ambiente que recebe seu valor, ao executar uma aplicação. Acredito que a tradução mais correta seja *códigos de retorno*.

Estes códigos são úteis para indicar que um programa foi finalizado de forma esperada ou não. São muito úteis em chamadas dentro de scripts, ou outros programas de linha de comando, onde o resultado da execução precisa ser confirmado ou tomada alguma ação em caso de falha.

Não existe um padrão, mas convencionou-se que a saída 0, é uma saída indicando sucesso, códigos maiores que 0 indicam que houve algum problema.

O programador pode criar uma lista de saídas a fim de codificar se ocorreu algum erro ou qual erro ocorreu.

Um exemplo abaixo do compactador **[7zip](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm)**:

> **0** No error
>     **1** Warning (Non fatal error(s)). For example, one or more
>   files were locked by some other application, so they were not
>   compressed.
>  
>     **2** Fatal error
>     **7** Command line error
>     **8** Not enough memory for
>   operation 
>     **255**   User stopped the process

*Uma curiosidade para Linux é que os códigos de erro são representados por um byte. Em alguns casos os programadores retornam códigos de erro com valor negativo para apontar erros. Neste caso se o código de erro for -1 para o linux será 255.*

Fontes:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php